# Confusion about Backbone.js and Django

Tags: javascript, django, rest, backbone.js, tastypie

I'm trying to use Backbone.js for my Django project and it's confusing. So to my understanding, I need `tastypie` for the RESTful API with Django to which I'm new, so for example I have a `SongResource` like follow :

```
class SongResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Song.objects.all()
        authorization = Authorization()
```

All what this does is gets back a list of all the songs I have in the database, right? To my understanding, I should use this in the Backbone.js router to get all the songs, and then do all the data manipulation in my JS code instead of the Django's view? 
So if I want to get all the songs that the logged-in user purchased, I should get all the songs from Django, and search for the user's songs in JS code? 
Also, what if I want to save songs the user listened to for example, I'm used to do that by sending an Ajax request to a view where I save the action.

Another thing is, let's say I have five models in my Django app, should I create the give models in Backbone.js too?
So in Backbone.js, I just get the data from Django and manipulate them in the front end instead of the Django views as I'm used to?

If you can see my confusion please guide me to some articles, tutorials, videos whatever !

Thanks a lot

Comment: Maybe thinking of the front- and back-systems as 'independent' from each other would help decouple your thought process :)

Answer (score 0):

You definitely have to do the filtering on Django side :) I know nothing about tastypie, but as of current (logged in) user, you have that in django session, therefore you cannot rely on `Meta.queryset`, instead the queryset changes for every request. You probably need to override some view method.

As of saving listened songs, you first decide when to do that (start or end of song), and upon that event you `save()` some `Listening` (Backbone) model, that will trigger the XHR request (see `Backbone.sync`).

Yes, you should Backbone model counterparts for your Django models if you use them client side. Again, see `Backbone.sync`

Comment: okay let's say the song is considered as `listened to` when it's finished. Backbone will send a request to Django, correct? if so, should I handle that request in a Django view in a "classical" way? So the point of the API is to just provide Backbone with data and allow it to manipulate it?

Comment: so for example, if in my router I have `/playlist/:id` that means that in my URLconf I must have something like `url(r'^playlist/(?P<id>.$)'` and assign a view that handles the request (like to save a created playlist etc etc)? Thank you for bearing with me.